# Volume of a square pyramid-- what's wrong in my analysis

Tags: calculus, geometry, volume

Note: Its not a duplicate. The other one talks about triple integrals... while I am only doing a single one..!

So to get the area of a cube I can do the following integral,

$$\int_0^a a^2 \, dh = a^3$$

So I try to do the same thing for the square pyramid-- taking the area to be $a\cdot a$, I do the following integral.

$$\int_0^h b^2 \left(1 - \frac{h}{H}\right)dh$$

Thinking that the factor $(1 - h/H)$ should take care of the reducing cross section.

Evaluating this integral gives me $b^2H/2$ while the correct volume happens to be $b^2H/3$.

I looked at the solution of calculating the volume and I get what its doing (calculating the area as a function of height) But I can't still get around why my reasoning is wrong.

Thanks and regards,
Dhruv Kapur.

Comment: Is this to be done with multiple integrals, or only a single integral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is to assume that as $h$ varies from $0$ to $H$, the *area* of the square at height $h$ decreases linearly. But it's the *side length* of the square that decreases linearly, so the *area* decreases quadratically. The *side length* of the square at height $h$ is $$
  L(h) = b\left(1 - \tfrac{h}{H}\right)
$$
so you have to integrate $L^2(h)$, i.e. compute $$
  V = \int_0^H (L(h))^2 \,dh = \int_0^H b^2\left(1-\tfrac{h}{H}\right)^2 \,dt \text{.}
$$

This yields $$
  V = b^2\left(\frac{h^3}{3H^2} - 2\frac{h^2}{2H} + h\right)\Bigg|_{h=0}^{h=H}
  = b^2\left(\frac{H}{3} - H + H\right) = \frac{b^2H}{3} \text{,}
$$
as it should.

Comment: Okk... that makes sense now :P Anyway could you tell me what would that structure look like, one whose area falls linearly with height?

Comment: You'd have to scale the length with $\sqrt{1 - \frac{h}{H}}$. Meaning the length would first decrease slower than for a pyramid, but then decrease faster and faster as $h$ gets larger, since the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ goes to $-\infty$ as $x$ goes to $0$. So the resulting volume would be a distorted pyramid which is wider than a real pyramid at the bottom, but leaner at the top. Or so I think - try plotting the resulting volume!